# Bash string compare cannot match

Tags: bash, mongodb

I want to filter some collections in mongodb to export. But the string compare seems incorrect.

`$1` in my case is `localhost:17017/mydb`

`shop` is one of the collections in mongodb, but `$i == 'shop'` never succeed.

```
#!/bin/bash

colls=`mongo $1 --eval 'db.getCollectionNames();' | tail -1`

IFS=',' read -ra ADDR <<< $colls

for i in "${ADDR[@]}"
do
    if [[ $i == 'shop' ]]
    then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

Or is there any other methods to export specified collections from mongodb?

Comment: are you trying to match "shop" or "'shop'"? if you need a partial match you can do `case "$i" in *shop*)echo $i;;esac` ... note the double quotes around $i, in case of odd characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to echo the values you got and see perhaps how you should actually use the patterns. Also please quote your variables properly. It's also better to use $() over backticks:

```
#!/bin/bash

colls=$(mongo "$1" --eval 'db.getCollectionNames();' | tail -1)
echo "colls: $colls"

IFS=',' read -ra ADDR <<< "$colls"
echo "colls count: ${#ADDR[@]}"

for i in "${ADDR[@]}"
do
    echo "Trying |$i|."
    if [[ $i == 'shop' ]]
    then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Somehow it prevents the contents of `$colls` from being re-evaluated with values of `IFS` before input.